# Is there a library to maintain MySQL table structure with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

My workflow for maintaining MySQL tables between my developer machines and my production server feels pretty sloppy and disorganized. I manually add columns on the production database tables after adding them on my developer machine. This causes the problem of sometimes forgetting to add the column (or the right column definition) on the production server or another developer machine. This problem will only grow as my company size grows (right now its just me working on this project).

Is there a library (preferably installable with composer) for PHP that automatically updates the table structure?

Comment: [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) has database migrations, but I don't know about a standalone library.

Comment: Add a script to your project that checks tables on launch. That way there is no problem with that. All people can develope this file than :) If it's a huge DB with a lot of tables and columns that has to be checked, use a version number and if this isn't the same checkt consistence and may update. (All depending on "if I got you right")

Comment: Once you get the design right, adding columns will become a vanishingly rare activity

Comment: I agree with @Strawberry actually you should build it right from beginning so there only be entrys and no edits (alter).

Comment: You could use doctrine migrations, flyWayDB migrations or similar.

Comment: @sectus what means utopia?

Comment: @Dwza, it's good to create once perfect DB structure and never change it. But it's unreachable on live and growing project. Everything could be changed hence database has to be changeable.

Comment: We just have a changes.sql file. Anytime a DB change was made, that sql query was added to the .sql file. Every time we promoted to production, we just ran that file. On successful run, move all those queries to a "already_promoted.sql" as a record that it was done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no quickfix for this. Long term solution would be to use a framework that supports migrations like Symfony or Yii.